# Async function which resolve a Promise and then returns a boolean?

Tags: typescript, promise

I have an async function that supposed to return a boolean if an entity exist based on a previous request call. Here is how it looks like:

```
async vertexExists(properties) {
    const nbVertices = await this.countVertices(properties);
    if (nbVertices !== 0) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Then in another function I call `vertexExists`:

```
if (await !this.vertexExists(entity)) {
        const response = await this.gremlinQuery(query);
        return response.body.result.data;
      }
```

But it seems not to wait `nbVertices` to be resolved and instead tells me immediately `false`.

Now, I know asynchronous functions are supposed to return a `Promise` and not a `boolean` but is there anyway to have a similar behaviour?

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Why do we need the await when calling the function in the "if" condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are negating the promise object. You will need to use

```
if (!(await this.vertexExists(entity))) {
```

or

```
if (await this.vertexExists(entity).then(x => !x)) {
```